# Codeigniter links not working without index.php in url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I developed one web application in which I used codeigniter, Structure of all the URLs of my web application is as follows:

```
<?php echo base_url();?>/Admin/Promotions
```

this type of links are working well in my **Localhost** but not working on my hosting server (*I'm using Godaddy hosting*)

But some links which have index.php in URLs are working both on localhost and server too structure of this king of links are

```
<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Admin/Pramotions
```

What shoud I do so that URLs without index.php works well ??

My HTACCESS :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what about your `.htaccess`?

Comment: index.php is removed by .htaccess fle. Check your .htaccess file

Comment: But how to work with links with no index.php e.g.(<?php echo base_url();?>/Admin/Promotions)

Comment: Add RewriteBase /your-Folder-Name/ after RewriteEngine On

Comment: Codeigniter automatically adds in the base url, you do not need to do this "<?php echo base_url();?>/Admin/Promotions"  Just use the last part, "Admin/Promotions"

Comment: Use `<?php echo base_url('admin/promotions');?>`.

Answer (score 4):

Use this **htaccess** --

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

then set **base_url** --

```
$config['base_url']='http://www.domain_name.com';
```

then remove index.php in config file --

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

after that it will work without index.php

Answer (score 1):

Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

Just replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

AND IN HTACCESS FILE put following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @Abhijit Kumbhar : answer provided

Answer (score 1):

If none of the answers above worked, perhaps you need to activate mod_rewrite in your httpd.conf:

On terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

ctrl + w to find for "rewrite"

Uncomment this line:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Save and restart httpd (apache).

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me ...`.htaccess` file is like this...

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

And don't forget to set

```
$config['base_url']='http://www.domain_name.com';
```

Comment: Is this htaccess code working for links with no index.php incuded ??

Comment: And using htaccess code given by you , Im getting error "No input file specified."